# When sharing from a website, how do I get the facebook share dialog to open with the facebook app on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, hyperlink, share

I am using the facebook SDK for javascript. I initialize it with `FB.init` and then I call the `share` method. This works fine on the PC. It correctly uses `popup` as the default `display` parameter, as stated on the [documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#params). On the same page, at the end of the description of the `display` parameter, it says:

> Mobile web apps will always default to the touch display type.

But when I am on my phone (android, chrome, website I want to share) it behaves the same way as on the PC, it opens a browser tab and asks me to log into facebook.

I guess that `touch` would be the right `display`, that is, opening the share dialog with the facebook app.

In other words, **I want it to have the same functionality as the *share* option of the browser itself** (on mobile).

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId            : 'xxxxxx',
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml            : true,
    version          : 'v8.0',
  });
};

function shareOnFacebook(){
  FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      href: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
      quote: 'The best site',
    }, function(response){})
}
```

```html
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>

<button onclick="shareOnFacebook();">Share on facebook</button>
```

Comment: _“I guess that touch would be the right display, that is, opening the share dialog with the facebook app.”_ - no, that is not what this parameter is for. _“I want it to have the same functionality as the share option of the browser itself (on mobile)”_ - that is not a thing you can achieve using `FB.ui`, the methods the JS SDK provides are explicitly for use in a mobile website context; you can not switch over from there to the native app directly.

Comment: _“I want it to have the same functionality as the share option of the browser itself (on mobile)”_ - then you should look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share